# List, not lose the reference 

Tags: c#, .net

Back from interview. I share with you and a good and precise answer is welcome.

The purpose, you have a static method, this method receive an `IList<int>` you have 
to get back the values you can divise by 3 and make the code.

Constraint :
The original list (in the main) has a reference on the stack and the values on the heap, 
the result must be return (it's a void method) in the same space (on the heap) than the original list. The solution show here is not correct because in the method a new pointer 
on the stack + heap are created in the method domain. Solution ?

Bonus : how change the code to receive not only int but float, double, ....

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<int> list = new List<int>() { 9, 3, 10, 6, 14, 16, 20};
        CanBeDivedByThree(list);
    }

    static void CanBeDivedByThree(IList<int> list)
    {
        list = (from p in list
                where p % 3 == 0
                orderby p descending
                select p).ToList<int>();
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

That's meaningless as the internal storage to an `IList` is not under your control. Adding (or possibly removing) items might re-allocate the internal data structures.

It is especially meaningless as the list in your sample contains *value* types which are copied anyway when you access them.

Last but not least it's basically the whole point of using a managed language that you don't have to worry about memory (al)locations. Such things are [implementation details](https://ericlippert.com/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/) of the platform.

To take up on your bonus question: There is no simple way to achieve that. One could think that using generics with a type constraint would solve the problem here (something like `static void CanBeDivedByThree<T>(IList<T> list) where T : struct`), but the problem is that C# does not (yet?) have support for generic arithmetic. C# doesn't have a modulo operator that can take a generic parameter of type 'T' and 'int'.

Comment: Details or not it's part of the interview questions even if I agree with you.

Comment: @Kris-I: Such questions are IMHO best answered by explaining why they don't make sense.

Comment: @0xA3: for a generic list it's reasonable to filter on a generic user-supplied predicate.

Comment: @0xA3: I meant something like the @CodeInChaos's approach: `void RemoveAll<T>(IList<T> list, Predicate<T> match)`.

Comment: I agree with the arguments. Even better: normaly there are more than one correct answers to a question. It only matters on your arguments...

Comment: I think it's just a badly written requirement. I think what was meant is that the result ends up in the instance of IList that was passed in, and not in a new instance.

Comment: Two options: either intentional trick question to see if you understand the concept of .NET as managed language, or they hired someone without much experience to write the questions. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
list.RemoveAll(n => n % 3 == 0);
```

or

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if (list[i] % 3 != 0)
        list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

The first approach works only for `List<T>`.

One could make it a template method, but remainder operation doesn't make much sense on floats.

Comment: Your starting index is off by one

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately only List but not IList does implement RemoveAll. So I first implement it as an extension method.

```
public static int RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> match)
{
  if (match == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("match");

  int destIndex=0;
  int srcIndex;
  for(srcIndex=0;srcIndex<list.Count;srcIndex++)
  {
    if(!match(list[srcIndex]))
    {
      //if(srcIndex!=destIndex)//Small optimization, can be left out
        list[destIndex]=list[srcIndex];
      destIndex++;
    }
  }
  for(int removeIndex=list.Count-1;removeIndex>=destIndex;removeIndex--)
  {
    list.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
  }
  return srcIndex-destIndex;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
list.RemoveAll(n => n % 3 != 0);
```

You can then use overloads for other types. Unfortunately you can't (easily) make it generic since generics don't work with operator overloading.

Comment: You could use `RemoveAt` (supported by `IList<>`) for clarity.

Comment: Typo I assume? - you should actually only keep the entries dividable by 3, not remove them.

Comment: @Vlad: Wouldn't RemoveAt result in a O(n^2) algorithm? @BrokenGlass Copy/Paste mistake from Vlad's solution

Comment: @CodeInChaos: it will. In this task here I prefer clarity over efficiency (remembering about the premature optimizations and letting the optimizer do the job).

Comment: @CodeInChaos: if you want to optimize even more, maybe the following would do: you can split the whole into 2 loops: loop #1 skips until found first non-matching item (no need to compare src/dest indices), and the loop #2 (which starts where the loop #1 finished) always copies (because src/dest indices are guaranteed not equal).

Comment: O(n) vs O(n^2) is quite relevant even for relatively small lists. And I view this as a general purpose library function. The check for equal indices is probably premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Others have covered the list part - this is just for the bonus bit.

You can't do this in a statically typed way using C# generics, but if you're using C# 4 you *can* do it with dynamic typing. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowDivisibleBy3(new List<int> { 1, 3, 6, 7, 9 });
        ShowDivisibleBy3(new List<decimal> { 1.5m, 3.3m, 6.0m, 7m, 9.00m });
    }

    static void ShowDivisibleBy3<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        foreach (dynamic item in source)
        {
            if (item % 3 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem is not lose the reference on the original heap section

Comment: @Kris-I: As expressed elsewhere, there's no guarantee about what implementation of `IList<T>` will be used. Heck, it could be a lazily generated one. If it were an explicit `List<T>` instead, that would be different.

Comment: Nice "hack" with `dynamic` :-) I agree that it would be different with an explicit `List<T>`; however we only know that the internal storage of a `List<T>` is an array. We don't know how this storage is managed and how and when the storage gets re-allocated. And even if we knew that (e.g. from Reflector) a patch or new framework version might change it.

Comment: @0xA3: Exactly, hence my comment.